# Why is ssh ignoring my ~/.ssh/config? Cannot commit to github

Tags: ssh, github, public-key, private-key

I have configured OpenSSH to use a specific key when I login to github....

```
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$ pwd
/home/mpenning/.ssh
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$ ls -la | grep config
-rw-r--r--  1 mpenning mpenning  473 Jan 23 09:49 config
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$ head -n 4 config
Host gh
        HostName github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$
```

However, when I ssh to github without explicitly calling out github's private key on the CLI, authentication fails:

```
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$ ssh -F ./config git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).    ^^^^^^^^ This used to work
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$
```

The only way I can force it to work is to explicitly call out the private key when I ssh...

```
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$ ls -la | grep github
-r--------  1 mpenning mpenning 3243 Nov 24  2016 id_rsa_github
-rw-r--r--  1 mpenning mpenning  743 Nov 24  2016 id_rsa_github.pub
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$ ssh -i ./id_rsa_github git@github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi mpenning! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$
```

My `config` file worked yesterday... I haven't changed anything in it.  The `config` file already points to the correct private key.

Suddely, ssh seemingly ignores my github config.  It never even tries the right private key...

```
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$ ssh -v git@github.com 2>&1 | grep github
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$
```

Obviously this works, but I shouldn't have to use -i...

```
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$ ssh -i id_rsa_github -v git@github.com 2>&1 | grep github
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: identity file id_rsa_github type 1
debug1: identity file id_rsa_github-cert type -1
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Offering RSA public key: id_rsa_github
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.253.113]:22).
Connection to github.com closed.
[mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$
```

My Questions:

- What broke this?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: Apart from what the answer says, you always use `ssh-agent`/`ssh-add`.

Comment: @DanielB, what advantage do ssh-agent / ssh-add have over my status quo

Comment: It’s simply a different way to deal with SSH public key authentication. It offers some minor benefits like having to enter a key’s passphrase only once (when calling `ssh-add`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not calling to connect to the host you've defined in your config.

Use `ssh gh` not `ssh .... git@github.com`

**But why? - See below:**

> [mpenning@mudslide .ssh]$ ssh -F ./config git@github.com Permission
>   denied (publickey).    ^^^^^^^^ This used to work

I don't think it ever did (did you check using history?). I think you used `ssh -F ./config gh`

You defined the host as `gh` in your config:

```
Host gh
        HostName github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
```

So you should simply be calling `ssh gh`. You can pass other arguments if you want to override what is in your config, such as if you wanted to use a different user however as you've set all the required variables you should just be using the Host variable and nothing more.

You shouldn't even need to pass the `-F ./config` to be honest.

Comment: I cannot understand why this worked for months and failed today... but changing my config name from ``gh`` to ``github.com`` worked

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

ensure your ~/.ssh/config is owned by your user and "staff" group (not root/root)